# django setting filter field with a variable

Tags: django, django-queryset

I show a model of sales that can be aggregated by different fields through a form. Products, clients, categories, etc.

```
view_by_choice = filter_opts.cleaned_data["view_by_choice"]

sales = sales.values(view_by_choice).annotate(........).order_by(......)
```

In the same form I have a string input where the user can filter the results. By "product code" for example.

```
input_code = filter_opts.cleaned_data["filter_code"]

sales = sales.filter(prod_code__icontains=input_code)
```

What I want to do is filter the queryset "sales" by the input_code, defining the field dynamically from the view_by_choice variable.

Something like:

```
sales = sales.filter(VARIABLE__icontains=input_code)
```

Is it possible to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [*dictionary unpacking* [PEP-448]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) here:

```
sales = sales.filter(
    **{'{}__icontains'.format(view_by_choice): input_code}
)
```

Given that `view_by_choice` for example contains `'foo'`, we thus first make a dictionary `{ 'foo__icontains': input_code }`, and then we unpack that as named parameter with the two consecutive asterisks (`**`).

That being said, I *strongly* advice you to do some validation on the `view_by_choice`: ensure that the number of valid options is limited. Otherwise a user might inject malicious field names, lookups, etc. to exploit data from your database that should remain hidden.

For example if you model has a `ForeignKey` named `owner` to the `User` model, he/she could use `owner__email`, and thus start trying to find out what emails are in the database by generating a large number of queries and each time looking what values that query returned.

Comment: Thanks Williem! It works perfectly. And thanks for the extra security advice.

Comment: Simply perfect! What more could I say about the answer?